# I want to know how to count with filter in spark withColumn

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

[image]

As shown in the picture, I want to extract the data using spark.

```
DataSetTest ro1 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 3);
DataSetTest ro2 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 4);
DataSetTest ro3 = new DataSetTest("car", "toy", "red", 1);
DataSetTest ro4 = new DataSetTest("bike", "toy", "white", 2);
DataSetTest ro5 = new DataSetTest("bike", "toy", "red", 5);
DataSetTest ro6 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 3);
DataSetTest ro7 = new DataSetTest("car", "toy", "white", 7);
DataSetTest ro8 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "green", 1);

Dataset<Row> df = session.getSqlContext().createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(ro1, ro2, ro3, ro4, ro5, ro6, ro7, ro8), DataSetTest.class);

private void process(){
    //1) groupByKey
    Dataset<Row> df2 = df.groupBy("keyword", "opt1", "prt2").sum("count");
    
    //2) counting by Opt & calculate the total number
    Dataset<Row> df3 = df2.withColumn("fruit_red", **???**)
            .withColumn("fruit_green", **???**)
            .withColumn("toy_red", **???**)
            .withColumn("toy_white",**???**)
            .withColumn("total_count", ???);
    
    //3) calculate the percent
    Dataset<Row> df4 = df3.withColumn("percent", df3.col("total_count").divide("??sum of total_count??"));
```

Can you know how to count in 2),3) part??

Comment: 2) using `pivot`, 3) get total count using window-function

Answer (score 3):

I am not a java expert but you can do something like this:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR) ;
DataSetTest ro1 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 3);
DataSetTest ro2 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 4);
DataSetTest ro3 = new DataSetTest("car", "toy", "red", 1);
DataSetTest ro4 = new DataSetTest("bike", "toy", "white", 2);
DataSetTest ro5 = new DataSetTest("bike", "toy", "red", 5);
DataSetTest ro6 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "red", 3);
DataSetTest ro7 = new DataSetTest("car", "toy", "white", 7);
DataSetTest ro8 = new DataSetTest("apple", "fruit", "green", 1);
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SaavnAnalyticsProject");
SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = sc.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(ro1, ro2, ro3, ro4, ro5, ro6, ro7, ro8), DataSetTest.class);

Dataset<Row> groupedDf = df.groupBy(col("keyword"), col("opt1"), col("opt2")).sum("cnt");
groupedDf = groupedDf.withColumn("concatCol", concat(col("opt1"), lit("_"), col("opt2")));
groupedDf = groupedDf.drop(col("opt1")).drop(col("opt2"));
groupedDf.show();
Dataset<Row> pivotedDF = groupedDf.groupBy(col("keyword")).pivot("concatCol").sum("sum(cnt)").na().fill(0);


String[] cols = ArrayUtil.removeFromArray(pivotedDF.columns(), "keyword");
String exp = String.join(" + ", cols);
System.out.println(exp);
pivotedDF = pivotedDF.withColumn("total", expr(exp));

pivotedDF.show();
```

in which result to this:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+
|keyword|fruit_green|fruit_red|toy_red|toy_white|total|
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+
|  apple|          1|       10|      0|        0|   11|
|    car|          0|        0|      1|        7|    8|
|   bike|          0|        0|      5|        2|    7|
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+
```

then:

```
Long sum = pivotedDF.agg(sum("total")).first().getLong(0);
pivotedDF = pivotedDF
         .withColumn("sum", lit(sum))
         .withColumn("percent", col("total")
                 .divide(col("sum"))).drop(col("sum"));
```

which result to:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+------------------+
|keyword|fruit_green|fruit_red|toy_red|toy_white|total|           percent|
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+------------------+
|  apple|          1|       10|      0|        0|   11|0.4230769230769231|
|    car|          0|        0|      1|        7|    8|0.3076923076923077|
|   bike|          0|        0|      5|        2|    7|0.2692307692307692|
+-------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-----+------------------+
```

you can achieve more readable code with python or scala